# SARIMAX mathematical equation

Tags: r, arima

Below is the summary of my SARIMA model:

```
Series: diff(log(data_final_ts)) 
ARIMA(0,0,2)(0,0,2)[4] with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
          ma1     ma2     sma1     sma2  intercept  exogeneous_var1  exogeneous_var2
      -0.7756  0.2152  -0.5155  -0.4023     0.0413           -1e-04           0.0028
s.e.   0.1358  0.1782   0.2985   0.2311     0.0068            0e+00           0.0347
      exogeneous_var3  exogeneous_var4
              -0.0054           0.0012
s.e.           0.0035           0.0049

sigma^2 estimated as 0.0001283:  log likelihood=182.13
AIC=-344.26   AICc=-339.68   BIC=-323.49

Training set error measures:
                        ME       RMSE         MAE      MPE     MAPE      MASE        ACF1
Training set -0.0002763522 0.01042586 0.008296043 83.07064 116.4007 0.4182354 0.006248187
```

I want to know if the following model equation is correct:

$$(1-B)(1-B^4)Y_t=(1+\phi_1 B^4+\phi_2 B^8)(1+\theta_1 B+\theta_2 B^2)e_t+\text{const}+\beta X_t$$

with $\text{const}$ being the mean of $Y_t$ and with $X_t$ including an intercept and a few exogenous variables.

Comment: Related question [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228667/how-to-put-the-coefficients-of-an-sarima-model-with-exogeneous-variables-in-an-e).

Comment: The leading two pairs of brackets should not be there. Why did you include them? They are for first differencing and for autoregressive terms, none of which appears in your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is a *regression with SARIMA errors* (rather than a SARIMAX model) and is given by the following equations:

$$
\begin{aligned}
y_t &= 0.0413 - 0.0001 x_{1,t} + 0.0028 x_{2,t} - 0.0054 x_{3,t} + 0.0012 x_{4,t}  + u_t, \\
u_t &= (1 - 0.7756\text{B} + 0.2152\text{B}^2)(1 - 0.5155\text{B}^4 - 0.4023\text{B}^{4\cdot2}) \varepsilon_t.
\end{aligned}
$$

What is left to do is to multiply the terms in brackets in the second equation carefully and to get the time indices right due to the backshift operator $\text{B}$.

(Note that the constant enters the model in a simple way because there are no autoregressive terms in the model. If there were some, the expression would be a bit more complicated. See Rob J. Hyndman's blog post ["Constants and ARIMA models in R"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimaconstants/).)

**Edit:** It looks like the variable supplied to the `arima` function that produced the output in the OP was a first difference of some other variable. Therefore, the model for the original (nondifferenced) variable would contain $(1-\text{B})$ in front of $y_t$.

Comment: SARIMAX models are a bit tedious and hence I cannot guarantee I did not make a mistake on the way. If I missed something, please notify me so that I could correct it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and for the two first term i taught they where the Non-seasonal diff and the seasonal diff terms like in the link below ? https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/9 s

Comment: @someone, but your model has `d=0` and `D=0`. Although now I see that your dependent variable is differenced *outside* the SARIMAX model (which you have not mentioned explicitly). If you ran the SARIMAX model on raw data, there would be one extra $(1-B)$ in front of $y_t$.

Comment: OK so the fact that i diff and seasonally adjusted the serie i don't have to put the 2 first terms ?

Comment: @someone, You posted a question about the model, and I answered it as such. Now  what you have done to the data before running the model is another issue.  If you differenced it, I gave the answer already. If you seasonally differenced it as well, I guess you know what to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard Hardy i wasn't clear and didn't specifie what i did to the data before running the arima model. thanks again for your time !

Comment: @someone, no problem, I am glad I could help!